# why my pie chart using google chart is not displayed on blade?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-visualization

I am trying to display the share of performance of various blog titles in terms of their engagement on a laravel blade in a piechart. *Engagement* here means sum of like and dislike. Here is my  function from **pagescontroller**.

```
 public function index()
    {
      $data = DB::table('posts')->select(DB::raw('title as title'),
                                          DB::raw('post_like + post_dislike as post_engage'))
                                          ->groupBy('title')
                                          ->get();
      $array[] = ['title', 'post_engage'];
      foreach($data as $key => $value)
      {
          $array[++$key] = [$value->title, $value->post_engage];
      }
      return view('pages.index')->with('title', json_encode($array));
    }
```

Here is my **pages.index**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
        <h1>Welcome to Larablog home</h1>
        <div id="pie_chart">
        </div>
        <h3> Array passed as title this is a debugging breakpoint only <br> {{$title}}</h3>
@endsection
@section('js')
    <script>
        var analytics = <?php echo $title; ?>
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart(){
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics);
                var options = {
                        title: 'Percentage of engagement share of blogs'
                };
                var chart = google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie_chart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);

        }
        

    </script>
    @endsection
```

Here is a part of my **layouts.app** which includes the google api script for piechart

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    @yield('js')
    
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

This is the output I get. MySql Query is executed as expected, data is properly passed on to the blade only no output as per google chart. Is the script wrong, api not working or anything else?
[image: Blade output]

Comment: Do a `console.log(typeof analytics)` and see what it contains. If it's a `string`, then `var analytics = <?php echo $title; ?>` isn't properly converting your PHP variable to a JS variable. If it's an `object`, then you _should_ be able to use it, but there might be other configuration issues (see the answer below)

Comment: @TimLewis console.log(typeof analytics) gives a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error. On clicking I see this array  [link](https://i.imgur.com/vBmx3j4.jpg)

Comment: @TimLewis I added some semicolon with the var statement and everything ran through till I get this javascript error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.Yd is not a function
    at Object.gvjs_uK [as PieChart] (jsapi_compiled_ui_module.js:1008)
    at drawChart ((index):26)` [index 26](https://i.imgur.com/ikM544G.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I've found that Google charts is fairly picky when it comes to reading the data set.  Your code looks correct for the display engine, but that array format in the dump might be your problem.

I typically load the data on the page via a data element.  Example:

```
<div id="timeChart" data-pie-info='{!! json_encode($chartArray)!!}'></div>
```

This gives the Google engine a JSON array to play with when I draw it in via JS, and it usually works well.  Try encoding your data with `json_encode` and see if this solves it for you.

Another item that I do a little differently in my code is the loading.  I know there are various versions, so this may be a non-issue.  But, here is how I load the pie chart for the version I use which incorporates the same draw syntax you are using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]}); 
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Comment: note: the version of google charts loaded by `jsapi` has been deprecated -- the version in the OP is correct...